# Deleting an Azure BotService with ArmClient returns invalid version

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-resource-manager

When I try to delete an azure bot service using an ARM client, I get back an error stating that about `version 2023-09-15-preview is invalid`. Sample code below:

```
var resourceGroupId = "ResourceGroupId";
var azureBotName = "BotName";
var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var resourceGroup = armClient.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupId);
var bot = await resourceGroup.GetGenericResourcesAsync($"resourceType eq 'Microsoft.BotService/botServices' and name eq '{azureBotName}'");
bot.First().DeleteAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);
```

The code worked and successfully deleted the bot until recently, and hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Azure recently changed the api versions that management.azure.com reports as valid, and the new ones are incorrect. If you run the powershell

```
Connect-AzAccount
((Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.BotService).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq botServices).ApiVersions
```

You'll see that `2023-09-15-preview` is the latest reported version, but it doesn't work, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.botservice/allversions doesn't include 2023-09-15-preview.

You can fix this by passing an api-version override into the ArmClient constructor. So if you start you code with

```
var options = new ArmClientOptions();
options.SetApiVersion(new ResourceType("Microsoft.BotService/botServices"), "2022-09-15");
var armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential, "SUBSCRIPTIONID", options);
```

then the delete will go through successfully.